# Dual Citizenship Travel in Europe For Extended Stay

Tags: schengen, europe, dual-nationality, tourist-visas

I'm trying to figure out the best way to have an extended stay in Europe and was wondering if this was possible with dual citizenship.

If I had a US and Singaporean passport, and traveled to a country in the Schengen area, either passport would give me a 90 day visa in a 6 month period.

Would this loophole be considered "legal" if say I travel to Spain using my Singaporean passport for 90 days, then went to UK or Ireland using my US passport, and reentered the Schengen area using my US passport. This would technically be me renewing my 90 day visa without needing to wait 90 days before doing so.

Comment: It's possible that you might not be caught, but immigration rules apply to you as a person, not to each passport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not going to work. The rule is that *you* may stay for 90 days out of each 180 days. No matter which passport you choose to use each time.

Comment: As Zach said, it might "work" but wouldn't be legal.

Comment: It is even very likely to 'work'. When you enter the Schengen area as a visa excempt tourist, due to the lack of a Schengen wide entry/exit register, the immigration officer must use the stamps in your passport to determine how much time you have spent in the Schengen area within the last 180 days. If you present a different passport and there are no other reasons to examine your person any further, you are very likely to be allowed entry without any issues.

Comment: While this might "work" for a short time, you'll undoubtedly do something that will cause you to reveal your scheme, like this guy: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/88186/2363