# Can two passports extend 90 day Schengen rule

Tags: visas, schengen, passports, dual-nationality, spain

I have an Irish and UK passport. Can I visit Spain for 90 days on my Irish passport, leave and come back straight away, and enter Spain on my UK passport and stay another 90 days?

Comment: No, but you can stay in Spain longer than 90 days on you Irish passport, but there might be restrictions like having to register.

Comment: If you, as a EU citizen, wish to stay longer than 3 months (have rented a house for 6 months), then you simply register that residence in the local town hall. You may be required to proof that you can support yourself and have heath insurance. [Move Spain as an EU Citizen: Get Your Registry Certificate](https://balcellsgroup.com/move-to-spain-as-an-eu-citizen/)

Comment: For future readers with two passports, none of which is an EU passport, the answer to the question in the title is no. The 90/180 rule applies per person, not per passport.

Comment: The most general answer to these kinds of questions is "are you two people?"

Comment: ***"I'd like to commit immigration fraud, is this a good way to go about doing it?"***

Comment: @user253751 In this case he's almost an Irishman and a POM :-) .

Comment: @Valorum Actually this question is more like: I'd like *not* to commit immigration fraud, is this loophole legal or not? And please do not overuse bold/italic for unnecessary emphasis.

Comment: This is even more of an "I am an EU citizen but I don't precisely know my rights as an EU citizen so I look for the loopholes first"

Comment: @fraxinus Yes, the usage of '90 days' instead of 'three months' makes that clear. Also the three months only applies to a **single** EU country, where as the 90 days applies for the whole Schengen Area. Good reasons to use the correct terminology.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24087/could-a-citizen-of-two-countries-eligible-for-90-180-schengen-stays-legally-rema

Comment: @JonathanReez Different situation since the one citizenship is an EU citizenship.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your Irish passport gives you the right to stay in Spain for longer than 90 days.

EU citizens who wish to reside in Spain for more than three months have to apply for a Certificate of Registration in the Oficina de Extranjeros (Foreigners Office) or if there is none in your region, at designated police stations.

Source: https://www.dfa.ie/irish-embassy/spain/our-services/new-to-spain/residency-and-entry-requirements/

Note that residing in Spain introduces other considerations, such as tax, health cover and medical insurance. See https://www.dfa.ie/irish-embassy/spain/our-services/new-to-spain/ for guidance.

Comment: Note that beyond a certain duration (most probably 6 months), there will also be tax implications (need to file returns and pay taxes in Spain rather than or in addition to Ireland).

Comment: After 90 days can I move to Portugal to avoid having to register?

Answer (score 13):

As [Traveller's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/179619/12011) describes, you can reside in Spain using only your Irish passport, since Ireland is part of the European Union, so long as you meet local registration requirements and abide by other laws that apply to residents of Spain. The 90 day limit does not apply when entering on your Irish passport. This would be true regardless of your possession of a second nationality.

However, regarding the title question of whether 2 passports can extend entry duration, the answer is no. Entry duration rules are not additive for dual-nationals. Someone who has two or more non-EU/Schengen passports cannot remain in Spain longer than 90 days out of any 180-day period without an appropriate visa.

Comment: The 90 day rule **does not apply** to EU citizens. After a 3 month stay (based on the Freedom of Movement Article 6 Right of residence for up to three months), re-entering as an UK citizen, with an entry stamp, the day count would be 0.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Correct. I didn't intend for my answer to suggest otherwise. Is there some part of it that needs clarification? (Note that the 2nd paragraph specifically refers to people with "two or more **non-EU/Schengen** passports.") Edit: I added a sentence to the first paragraph to make this more explicit.

Comment: Well, the titel itself should be '2, non-EU, passports' to make the situation clearer.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Well, in this case, the title question probably should have specifically referred to an Irish and UK passport to match the question body, but since it just says "two passports," I added this answer for other people who may find this question in a Google search due to the title, but have two non-EU nationalities. If OP changes the title to specify Irish + UK, then I'll delete this answer. Traveller's answer does a good job dealing with the scenario that OP was actually interested in, but, unfortunately, the question title doesn't match that, so I added this one to deal with it.

Comment: @MarkJohnson do you mean to imply one can get around the registration requirement by using two passports in the Ireland/UK situation?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann No, the purpose of the comment was to make it clear that the *Freedom of Movement Article 6* 3 month rule and *Schengen Border Code Article 6(1)* 90 day rule are 2 seperate entities under immigration law. The registration requirement/law would probably treat this situation as one person staying longer than 3 months without registration.